# Prefix of the Year to a column and achieve it though trigger and auto increment

Tags: mysql

I would like to have the prefix of the Year to a column and achieve it though trigger and auto increment. My trigger is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_table_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON Table 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO T_Seq VALUES (NULL); 
SET NEW.id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y%m'), LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, '0')); 
END
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

I tried gone through many sites but the syntax is same and could not identify the place, where I did the mistake. Please have a look and let me know, if you found one.

Many Thanks for your time in advance.

Regards,
Chaitanya

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABE for `Table`. Does `T_Seq` table contains the only column which is AI+PK? Do you remember about DELIMITER? What is the client which executes this trigger creation? What is precise server version? The code itself is correct: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=256654f24fcb5c40737158465261d80a).

Comment: Thanks. Complete Create table is as follows: create table Table
(
id int not null key
); and the complete T_Seq table is CREATE TABLE T_Seq
    (
      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ); client is squirrel sql. Database version 8.0.21

Comment: If so then the only possible reason is lost DELIMITER reassigning statement.

Comment: Yes Akina. You are right, it is absolutely delimiter issue. I had executed the same in CLI and it went fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely delimiter issue. I had executed the same in CLI and it went fine.

Step 1: delimiter //

Step 2: CREATE TRIGGER Trg_table_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON Table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO T_Seq VALUES (NULL);
SET NEW.id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y%m'), LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, '0'));
END; //

Step 3: delimiter ;